# move 14.04 from HD to SSD and new HD - in what order

Tags: ssd

I have 14.04 installed on a 1T HB, that is at 90% capacity.
I've ordered 120G SSD and a 3T HD, that I want to migrate to.
Wondering in what order I should do so?

1. install the SSD, and move the OS to it, then add the new HD, and move the remaining data to it.
2. install the new HD, migrate everything to it, then install the SSD, and migrate to OS to it.
3. some other option that I'm not seeing?

Comment: It rather depends on your current partioning arrangement & sizes. Are you able to provide that (output of df -h should do nicely)?

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1       896G  763G   88G  90% /

none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

udev            3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev

tmpfs           774M  1.6M  772M   1% /run

none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

none            3.8G   23M  3.8G   1% /run/shm

none            100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user

encfs           896G  763G   88G  90% /home/rdlong/Dreams_aaa


encfs is just a a small encrypted directory
sorry about the format -

Answer (score 0):

I would move the data to the HDD first, then the system to the SSD - that way you don't run out of space & can use recursive copy/move without duplicating.

The way I did this was to create a smallish partition - 15G IIRC - for boot & most of the smaller directories, around 20G for /usr, and the remainder of the SSD for /home (I tend to install lots of packages over the years!) using `gparted`, and create folders for 'Stuff' on the large HDD; along the lines of `cd /path_to_3TBdrive ; mkdir Music Movies Documents`... & then move out large files from my /home to the new HDD, finally copying the remainder of the system over using a live CD - you can then move the system folders while they're not mounted, re-write /etc/fstab to suit (the SSD copy of course!), put the [small enough] residue of your /home folder into the 3rd SSD partition, use grub to make the SSD boot & you're done.

There is sufficient info in askubuntu that I haven't re-written the detail on this part!